# SQL Prefix for arcpy.da.SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor

Does the sql prefix - `DISTINCT` work well on SDE tables?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Syntax:

```
SearchCursor (in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})
```

An SQL prefix clause is positioned in the first position and will be inserted between the SELECT keyword and the SELECT COLUMN LIST. The SQL prefix clause is most commonly used for clauses such as `DISTINCT` or `ALL`.

My following example is resulting in all rows, not distinct rows.

```
rs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sTableName, (sSelectField1, sSelectField2), sSqlExp, None, None, ("DISTINCT", sSqlPostfix))
```

1. What else could I do to get truly distinct records only?
2. I store the values in a list and is there a function to get unique values in a list?

   Example [1,2,2,3,3,3,5,6,7] to [1,2,3,5,6,7]. Also set(xyz) won't work because I'm using a list, whereas set(xyz) works on tuples.

Comment: You have two select fields in your column list. You should be getting a unique list of these column pairs.  Another option would be to try a GROUP BY in your postfix

Comment: @MickyT, that's what I thought "DISTINCT" would do. But it didn't, strangely. Also, GROUPBY in the postfix didn't work but ORDERBY works.

Comment: This thread may help shed a little light https://geonet.esri.com/thread/91400  It may be that the objectid is also coming through.  What version of Arc are you using?

Comment: @MickyT, Thanks for the useful thread. I'm using 10.1 SP 1. Still, DISTINCT and GROUPBY wont work. 
-------
With DISTINCT it wont throw any error and still provide an incorrect query result. ------- With GROUPBY I get this error "RuntimeError: Underlying DBMS error [Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0: Column 'V__318.OBJECTID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.]" ------- It leads me too believe that its a bug like you suggested. Can you try replicating if you can with your SDE/SQL Server

Comment: It appears that the objectid is what is causing your problem.  With the group by option try adding MAX(objectid) or MAX(OID@) to your select list.  Here's a workaround someone else did https://geonet.esri.com/message/309816#309816

Comment: Nope didn't work. Adding MAX(OBJECTID) or MAX(OID@) to select didn't work. So is arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute. Its damn frustrating.

Comment: To do this I would run [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with a case field first, and a statistic of COUNT, and then open the SearchCursor on the table that results

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would:

1. run Summary Statistics (Analysis) with a case field and a statistic of COUNT, and
2. open the SearchCursor on the table that results